# MongoDB - how to search for a value across two fields?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a simple collection that looks like this:

```
{'sold': 'Test1', 'bought': 'Test2'}, {'sold': 'Test3', 'bought': 'Test3'}, {'sold': 'Test3', 'bought': 'Test1'}
```

I need to get all the records where `Test1` is either in `sold` or `bought`, so in thi case i should get the first and third records.

I tried this: `db['orders'].find({'$or': [{'sold': 'Test1', 'bought': 'Test1'}]})`, but the problem with this query is that it tries to get all the records where both `sold` and `bought` are equal to `Test1`. How can i get, instead, the records where `sold` or `bought` is equal to `Test1`?

Comment: is this a dictionary? in that case you could just do something like `[x for x in lst if 'Test1' in x.values()]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are able to do this by

```
db['orders'].find({'$or': [{'sold': 'Test1'}, {'bought': 'Test1'}]})
```

The `$or` operator expects a list of expressions, which are in your case `{'sold': 'Test1'}` and `{'bought': 'Test1'}`

```
{ $or: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> }, ... , { <expressionN> } ] }
```

for more details check out [mongodb docs for OR](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/).

Happy trading :-)

Comment: Ok my bad, i had no idea why i was trying with the two expressions in the same dict.. Thank you a lot! Happy trading!